# Feature selection for predicting apparent temperature using correlation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, correlation, feature-selection

I have a data frame as shown and I am trying to reduce the features based on Pearson correlation. I am trying to basically predict whether the apparent temperature is increasing over the years from 2006 - 2016
[image: This is the data frame showing correlations between difference feature columns]

What I want to know is that is it a good idea to delete a column if its correlation is weak with the target column(which is the apparent temperature)?

[image: Here is a weak correlation between apparent temperature and wind speed, so should I discard wind speed column?]

Also, I am using Pearson correlation

Comment: Could you please paste code to generate the dataframe? otherwise anyone trying to solve your question would have to handcraft it himself. Just do `df.to_dict()` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: It seems like if you're trying to determine whether temperature is increasing between 2006 and 2016, you could take the "Apparent Temperature" column as your y value, take the year as your x value, and do a linear regression. Why use any other variables? I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve.